# Generate random numbers in a range with some others excluded

Tags: digital-logic, system-verilog, rtl

I need to generate random number between 0 and 191. This will fit in 8 bits. Then depending on certain constants being defined or not, certain slices of this range shall be included or excluded. e.g pseudocode

```
#if feature_1 == 1
  range 7 to 31 included
#endif
#if feature_2 > 3
  range 55 to 72 included
#else
  range 60 to 79 included
#end if
```

This number is required for use in a part of a digital design. The module must be combinatorial so that it can do the stuff within a single clock cycle. I can see that the first part of getting a random number is solved using LFSR PRNG. Then, the result can be limited to 0 to 191 by causing the LFSR output to be wrapped around if it exceeds 191. Atleast, this is the trivial approach. But, how do I design the other part where only numbers in certain ranges can occur as the final output?

The numerical values correspond to certain commands. Therefore, for the module that is being designed, depending on the parameters used during compile (that #if part), certain features will be included or not in the design. Thus, if a feature is not present and the random number generates an output that invokes it in the final randomly generated command, the design will lock up.

Why do I need random number you might ask, well it has to do with a hardware based testbench. I cannot go into more details. The random number approach has worked well so far except here where I need to excluded certain values.

Comment: `wrapped around if it exceeds 191` that will reduce randomness

Comment: I do not need "true randomness". This is question is about EE since I am designing a module to be implemented on ASIC.

Comment: This is system verilog and those questions are on topic, I would send this to stack overflow, but verilog questions are more likely to be answered here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

True random number generators are expensive and normally used for research.

You did not specify how random the set of numbers needed to be.  However, you hinted that you already are satisfied with your current random number generator. Let us work with what you already have then.

Consider your random number generator which is already creating numbers in a specified range. Reconfigure your random number generator to create a set of numbers. First the in large range, then again for each of the smaller ranges. Use the logic outlined above to pick which range or ranges to use.  If there is more then one range, create an additional random number to indicate which range is to be used for the final random number.

Comment: Someone may argue that because I did not specify all the smaller ranges had to be of the same size then there is a possibility of uneven distribution (again, we don't know what the OP is using for a random number generator).  But I'm thinking the OP is not that interested in a perfectly random number.

Comment: I am using LFSR so it does not need to be truly random.

Comment: Please delete your answer and I will delete this question, it has been closed off anyway. It was a mistake to have posted it. Sorry.

Comment: Actually, there are many stackexchange web sites.  There is a [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) if you want to post the question there. Each stackexchange site has its own rules. But I think a closed question is not visible to most users. The other option is to re-word the question w/an electronics bent ... then someone might re-open.

Comment: I flagged the question asking if it could be migrated to https://math.stackexchange.com/.